# TThread Creation of TButton Parented By TPanel

Tags: multithreading, delphi, button, panel, lazarus

I have a question about Separate `TThread` creation of a MainThread `TButton` on a MainThread `TPanel`.  The `TPanel` must be set as the `TButton`'s Parent.

```
ButtonVariableName := TButton.Create (
    (Form1.FindComponent('PanelNameString') as TComponent)
   );

ButtonVariableName.Parent := (
    (Form1.FindComponent('PanelNameString') as TWinControl)
  );
```

is not working...

`ButtonVariableName` is on MainThread.
`TButton.Create()` is being called on Separate TThread.
`ButtonVariableName.Parent` is also called from Separate `TThread`.

`FindComponent` seems to be what is breaking down.  When I remove it and place something else there it works.  It may be that `FindComponent` doesn't work when called from Separate `TThread` but I'm not certain.

Any pointers^?
LOL.

-i2programmer

Comment: Windows have affinity with the thread on which they are created. In practice this makes it practically impossible to build a UI with multiple threads. It's also pointless. Put the UI in the main thread and run long running non-visual tasks out of threads.

Comment: Give up - there is absolutely no point in even attempting to use threads with UI controls.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use VCL from secondary threads. Use Synchronize or Queue in the secondary thread to execute VCL-related code in the context of the main thread.

Comment: This is how I'm calling:
It does include Synchronize();

`procedure TMyThread.forButton;
begin
  Buttons[ItemCounter]      :=
    TButton.Create((Form1.FindComponent(tsl[0 + 3]) as TComponent)); 

Synchronize(@forButton);` but still it functions not.

Comment: @i2programmer: On StackOverflow you can edit your question. It would be more helpful to include the code from your comment in your question and format it properly (use the {} button, or simply indent yourself by four spaces).

Answer (score 1):

This was supposed to be a comment but I want to include some code. First of all you're not supposed to call any VCL from secondary threads, so calling `FindComponent` is not guaranteed to work. Despite this fact, I doubt this is your problem, because unless you're especially lucky you will not get a race condition so you will not get an error.

You should do two things:

- Put your code under a simple button on a form, test it, and when you know the code is good, move it to your background thread.
- Brake up your code a bit so you can see what's failing where. No need to guess if `FindComponent` is the one that's failing when it's so easy to test and be sure.

Brake up your code like this:

```
var ParentPanel: TWinControl;
    anControl: TControl;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(Form1)); // Assertions are free, you might as well test everything
  anControl := Form1.FindComponent('YourNameHere'); // casting straight to TWinControl raises an error if the returned control is nil
  Assert(Assigned(anControl)); // Make sure we got something
  ParentPanel := anControl as TWinControl; // raises error if the control is not TWinControl
  ButtonVariableName := TButton.Create(ParentPanel);
  ButtonVariableName.Parent := ParentPanel;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type
  TMyThread = class( TThread )
  private
    FOwner : TComponent;
    procedure DoCreateButton;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

.....

{ TMyThread }

constructor TMyThread.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;

  FOwner := AOwner;
  Resume;
end;

procedure TMyThread.DoCreateButton;
begin
  with TButton.Create(FOwner) do
  begin
    //Set the button Position 
    Left := 5;
    Top := 5;

    Parent := FOwner as TWinControl;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(DoCreateButton);
end;


{ Form1 }

procedure TForm1.btnExecClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TMyThread.Create(Panel1);
end;
```

Comment: +1 for code that looks like it would do what the OP wants. But the question still remains: WHY??   
IMO, follow the advice given, and avoid doing this in a thread.

Comment: -1 This is pointless. Create a thread just so that you can serialise back to the main thread. Why?!

Comment: Maybe because TMyThread.Execute will do OTHER things than just create a button...  With that being said, I think what the OP is trying to achieve is to update the UI according to what happens inside the thread (Maybe add a cancel button after the thread has been running for more than X seconds...).  The right way to do this would probably to add a callback to the main thread and let it deals with the button creation.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: The code is mere a demonstration using TThread.Synchronize, of course if you see from a practical view it is pointless. But like Ken said it doesn't mean the Thread only executes Button creation, it can do other things than just create buttons. I'm simply answering the OP's question, that's all.

Comment: Btw I do agree that using a Method Call Back to main thread is a more straightforward solution than using Synchronize :)